# How do I pass an object to the next flow from a flow in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Here I have 3 different flows and I'm using spring integration dsl. Let's assume we have prepared an object in flow 1 and I want to pass that object to other flows without disturbing the actual payload that's coming from the gateway. So I just want to add the object somehow in somewhere but not changing the actual payload so that I can use that object in subsequent flows. I can pass that in header but will that be correct to send a big object in header?

Here I'm using scatter gather pattern with three parallel flows.

```
     @Bean
      public IntegrationFlow flow() {
                return flow ->
                    flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
                        .split()
                        .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                        .scatterGather(
                            scatterer ->
                                scatterer
                                    .applySequence(true)
                                    .recipientFlow(flow1())
                                    .recipientFlow(flow2())
                                    .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                            gatherer ->
                                gatherer
                                    .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                                    .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2))
                        .aggregate(lionService.someMethod())
        // here I want to call other Integration flows
                        .gateway(someFlow())
                        .to(someFlow2());
  
            }

//Here in this flow I'm calling prepareCDRequestFromLionRequest method in the handle(). This method returns an object1 which is one of the payload(among 3) that will be used after aggregation but I want to prepare another object2 in this method and somehow want to send that object2 to the someFlow() or someFlow2() but I want object1 as a payload. 
    
     @Bean
      public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return flow ->
            flow.channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.errorChannel("flow1ErrorChannel", true))
                .handle(cdRequestService, "prepareCDRequestFromLionRequest");
      }
    //same way I have flow2 and flow3


//validateRequest method
  public Object1 validateRequest(LionRequest lionRequest) {
    lionValidationHelper.validateRequestAttributes(lionRequest);

   // validation code goes here after creating a new request object which will go to the parallel flows
Object1 obj1 = someLogicTocreateTheObject1
Object2 obj2 = someLogicTocreateTheObject2
    return object1;
  }
```

*UPDATE - Now as u see above I'm sending object1 as a payload but I need object2 to be sent from here somehow so that I can make use of this object2 in other subsequent flows. This Object2 is a POJO and having different fields so in other flows I'll be getting relevant information which I'll be setting to it's fields. And finally I'll be getting an object which then I'll be using in someFlow(). So I want object to be passed and enhancing that object in different flows that I have.

Or let's suppose after validateRequest I want to create an object and want to pass that to the parallel flows/someFlow somehow but I don't want to hamper the payload that will be coming to the flows. By using header it's achievable but is there a different way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to see your flows topology and more details about your solution, but there is indeed no problem to transfer big objects in the message headers.

You perhaps may also look into a publish-subscribe or recipient-list solution to send the same message to different sub-flows. This way you can do in those sub-flows whatever you need with request without looking into headers.

**UPDATE**

So, according your comment about scatter-gather, it sounds like you want to distribute a message to the recipients, gather their results and then continue together with an original, request message.

Since you say that you'd like do not send an extra header to those recipients, but still preserve a request message for post-gather processing, then you may look into a `enrich()` EI pattern, where your scatter-gather would be a request sub-flow. There you can decide to add a gather result into a header or property of the request payload (if that is possible).

See more info about Content Enricher in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher

Comment: Hi Artem so the usecase is same old scatter gather pattern where I'm calling three parallel flows and after that aggregating and one more flow. I don't want to send anything between these parallel flows but want to send from any of the parallel flows to the flow after aggergation.

Comment: I'll add the code in the post.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Can u please see my update. I've added the code so that u have some perspective.

Comment: Right. That's what I try to explain you in my answer. just after that `handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")` you go an `enrich()` and extract whatever you want into a separate sub-flow. The result of that sub-flow you store in a header or property of the request payload. Then you continue a main flow with already two data types - request message and scatter-gather result. Not sure what else you'd like to hear from me...

Comment: But what do I do with object2? I can't return that in validateRequest method right? Because already validateRequest method is returning object1. Sorry I didn't understand that.

Comment: OK. Then just start your flow with an `enrich()` endpoint then! This way even that `validateRequest` would be a part of an enrichment sub-flow. You probably need to give more details in your question what you'd like to preserve and at what point you lose it. And where you'd like to reuse it. Instead you talk about scatter-gather details. But the question has nothing to do with that. Sorry, you are confusing us...

Comment: Kindly see an update in the post if it make any sense to you.

Comment: No, that's more confusion. Now I see even more objects than you talk about: `lionRequest`, `obj1`, `obj2`, `object1`. Which of them you'd like to preserve and use in the subsequent flow? Perhaps exactly this must not be available for your scattter-gather, but rather whatever you can create from the `validateRequest()` method. Then still my suggestion for the `enrich()` is applicable. Did you try to look into that? It is really hard for me to understand your business logic when I don't see the whole picture

Comment: lionRequest is the object that's coming from gateway to this main flow. In validateRequest method I validate that lionRequest object and return a new object which is obj1. So obj1 is my payload which is being passed to the 3 parallel flows. Also I'm creating another object obj2 that I want to return somehow and want to use that in different flows sameway how we use header information. That obj1 will be as is but the obj2 will be passed to the different flows and by using different flows information obj2 will be getting it's field values.

Comment: Ok. Since there is no multi-return in Java, we don’t have choice unless return any kind of iterable or the whole message with extra headers. You then can remove that header whenever you don’t need it.

Comment: Somehow can I pass that object through some channel to the other flows?

Comment: Yes, there is no problems to send a message directly from your service activator method.